# Field initializer cannot reference non static field, method, property

Tags: c#, mailchimp

I am using [MailChimp](https://github.com/brandonseydel/MailChimp.Net) Library by brandonseydel, i am not able to create the 'MailChimpManager' object,getting the error  a field initializer cannot reference non static field,method,property

```
 public string MailChimpAPIKey {
        get
        {
            using (BEntities entity=new BEntities())
            {
                var key = entity.tbl_Client_MailChimp_Settings.Where(p => p.CIN == CINNo).FirstOrDefault();
                if (key != null)
                    return key.APIKey;
                else
                    return "";
            }
        }
    }

    private static MailChimpManager Manager = new MailChimpManager(MailChimpAPIKey);
```

Comment: Error speaks for itself. You are trying to access non static object in your static method. Remove static or make MailChimpAPIKey static.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use non-static filed with static class. Make your `MailChimpAPIKey` static and it will work. Also try to implement setter for `MailChimpAPIKey`.

Comment: i tried that but i am fetching the record based on CIN in MailChimpAPIKey property ,CINNo is again a property which is non static

Comment: remove static from MailChimpManager. You kept is as private so will not be accessible anywhere.

Comment: how to fetch logged in user id and store it in static variable in asp.net mvc

Comment: That is different error or question you are asking. You can start separate question for that. If this helped you, upvote and mark as answer.

Answer (score 0):

MailChimpAPIKey must be also static, or implement of IMailChimpManager must be non static

```
private IMailChimpManager Manager = new MailChimpManager(MailChimpAPIKey);
```